# Track a single object when multiple objects are present in a static field

Tags: opencv, processing

I'm trying to track a single moving object in a static field when multiple objects are present. With the help of a great mentor i got the following code. I'm using opencv for processing library. but when the code is complied i get an error :
cannot convert from element type from 
     ArrayList to ArrayList>   at the line : 
    for (ArrayList< ArrayList > blob : blobgp )

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;
 int x, y;

  OpenCV opencv;
   Capture cam;

   ArrayList<Contour> contours;
   PVector previousPosition;

  void setup() {
  cam = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2);
   size(cam.width, cam.height);
   opencv = new OpenCV(this, cam.width, cam.height);
   opencv.useGray();
   opencv.startBackgroundSubtraction(5, 3, 0.1);

   cam.start();
   previousPosition = new PVector();
   }

  void draw() {

  track();
  stroke(255, 0, 0); 
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(5); 
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
 }
void track() {

        image(cam, 0, 0);
 opencv.loadImage(cam);
 opencv.updateBackground();
 opencv.erode();
 opencv.dilate();
 ArrayList<Contour> contours = opencv.findContours(false, true);
 ArrayList<Contour> contourblobs =new ArrayList<Contour>();
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blobgp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>>();
 contourblobs.add(contours.get(0));
 blobgp.add(contourblobs);

 for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++) {
ArrayList<Contour> remainingcontour =new ArrayList<Contour>();
remainingcontour.add(contours.get(i));

PVector contourCenter = centerOfContour(remainingcontour);

boolean matchesExistingBlob = false;

for (ArrayList< ArrayList<Contour> > blob : blobgp ) {
  PVector blobCenter = centerOfBlob(blob);
  if (PVector.dist(blobCenter, contourCenter) < threshold) {
    blob.add(contour);
    matchesExistingBlob = true;
  }
}
// if it didn't match an existing blob
// create a new one
if (!matchesExistingBlob) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> newBlob =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>>();
  newBlob.add(contour);
   }
 }

// now use unique blobs to draw the dots:
for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blob : blobgp) {
PVector c  = centerOfBlob(blob);

x=c.x;
y=c.y;

  }
}  




 // helper functions

PVector centerOfContour(ArrayList<Contour> remainingcontour) {
PVector result = new PVector();
int numPoints = 0;
 for (PVector p : contour.getPoints()) {
  result.x += p.x;
  result.y += p.y;
  numPoints++;
}
 result.x /= numPoints;
 result.y /= numPoints;
 return result;
 }

 PVector centerOfBlob(ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blob) {
  PVector result = new PVector();
  for (ArrayList<Contour> contour : blob) {
    PVector contourCenter = centerOfContour(contour);
    result.x += contourCenter.x;
    result.y += contourCenter.y;
   }
 result.x /= blob.size();
 result.y /= blob.size();
 return result;
 }
 }
```

Comment: can you please post a code sample that can be compiled by other people ? Also it's slightly odd that you're declaring blobgp like so:`ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blobgp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>>();` (a list of lists of contours I'm guessing), but you traverse it like so:`for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blob : blobgp)` and my rough guess is perhaps you should traverse it like so `for (ArrayList<Contour> blob : blobgp)`. Again, having more context will help

Comment: I have changed the codes to include every part of it!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a better understand of the code you use.

For example, you can get rid of the syntax errors if you are careful with what arguments your functions expect and what you pass to them:

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
float x, y;

OpenCV opencv;
Capture cam;

ArrayList<Contour> contours;
PVector previousPosition;
int threshold = 20;

void setup() {
  cam = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2);
  size(cam.width, cam.height);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, cam.width, cam.height);
  opencv.useGray();
  opencv.startBackgroundSubtraction(5, 3, 0.1);

  cam.start();
  previousPosition = new PVector();
}

void draw() {

  track();
  stroke(255, 0, 0); 
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(5); 
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
}
void track() {

  image(cam, 0, 0);
  opencv.loadImage(cam);
  opencv.updateBackground();
  opencv.erode();
  opencv.dilate();
  ArrayList<Contour> contours = opencv.findContours(false, true);
  ArrayList<Contour> contourblobs =new ArrayList<Contour>();
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blobgp = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>>();
  if(contours.size() > 0){
    contourblobs.add(contours.get(0));
    blobgp.add(contourblobs);

    for (int i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++) {
      ArrayList<Contour> remainingcontour =new ArrayList<Contour>();
      remainingcontour.add(contours.get(i));

      PVector contourCenter = centerOfContour(remainingcontour);

      boolean matchesExistingBlob = false;
      PVector blobCenter = centerOfBlob(blobgp);
        if (PVector.dist(blobCenter, contourCenter) < threshold) {
          blobgp.add(contours);
          matchesExistingBlob = true;
        }
      /*
      for (ArrayList< ArrayList<Contour> > blob : blobgp ) {
        PVector blobCenter = centerOfBlob(blob);
        if (PVector.dist(blobCenter, contourCenter) < threshold) {
          blob.add(contour);
          matchesExistingBlob = true;
        }
      }
      */
      // if it didn't match an existing blob
      // create a new one
      if (!matchesExistingBlob) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> newBlob =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>>();
        newBlob.add(contours);
      }
    }

    // now use unique blobs to draw the dots:
    /*
    for (ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blob : blobgp) {
      PVector c  = centerOfBlob(blob);

      x=c.x;
      y=c.y;
    }
    */
    PVector c  = centerOfBlob(blobgp);
      x=c.x;
      y=c.y;
    }
}  

// helper functions

PVector centerOfContour(ArrayList<Contour> remainingcontour) {
  PVector result = new PVector();
  int numPoints = 0;
  for (Contour contour : contours) {
    for (PVector p : contour.getPolygonApproximation().getPoints()) {
      result.x += p.x;
      result.y += p.y;
      numPoints++;
    }
  }
  result.x /= numPoints;
  result.y /= numPoints;
  return result;
}

PVector centerOfBlob(ArrayList<ArrayList<Contour>> blob) {
  PVector result = new PVector();
  for (ArrayList<Contour> contour : blob) {
    PVector contourCenter = centerOfContour(contour);
    result.x += contourCenter.x;
    result.y += contourCenter.y;
  }
  result.x /= blob.size();
  result.y /= blob.size();
  return result;
}
```

While the above code will compile and run I doubt it will do what you're after. This brings us to the question: what are you trying to achieve. " trying to track a single moving object in a static field when multiple objects" sounds vague. How should your algorithm above work ? (what is `blobgp` ? is seems to only deal with the first contour (`contours.get(0)`), etc.).

Are you simply trying to display the center of the moving blob in a scene that may contain multiple blobs ? If you have multiple blobs and only one is moving and you're interested in it, can you not simply subtract the background first, so the moving blob will be the only detected blob ?

Comment: Going through your explanations, still could use a few explanations: 2)loop through the remaining contours and find the average of their distance. (what is this distance ? from the centre of each contour to a given point/to a each other contour ? excluding the 1st contour ?) 3)use the contours to find the average of their center points: this simply getting the each contours' centroid, correct ? 4)if the distance between the 2 averages is less than a value then add the contours to the array where one element is stored initially, else create a new object...

Comment: ...so compare the distances between contour centroids in pairs and if a pair comparison passes a threshold value then add this contour to the list that originally stored just the 1st contour (regardless of what that might be ) ? otherwise, create what sort of object and what is it's purpose ? 5) use those contours to find the average of the center points so that we track only one moving body : so loop through the contours that passed the threshold test, get average their centroid positions and use this value as the result of your tracking ? This is your project and should be familiar with it..

Comment: ...but bare in mind that others aren't so please try to look at this from a different point of view: someone who isn't as immersed into and actually has never seen your project and knows nothing about your project to begin with. How would you explain what you're trying to achieve, one step at a time so anyone can understand ? Please update your question accordingly

Comment: Ok .. well my objective in simple words is to track a single person in the field of view and find the co-ordinate of the center of his bounding box, considering that at least 2 people are in the field of view! yes Im trying to get the centroid. Doing that is easy if I consider using simple frame differencing, but when using the background subtraction function given in opencv for processing it becomes complicated. That is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: It's also tricky that you're using this outdoors and your background changes a lot. Would it be possible to post a few frames of a typical setup ? I have another idea that might work: how about detecting people ? One reliable way is to use opencv's HoG(histogram of oriented gradients) method, but that's computationally expensive and you won't be able to use it in real time. Another way is using a haar casade (same way you detect a face, but notice in the folder containing the xml cascades you also have one for people detection). Perhaps if you get a sweet spot ratio between the...

Comment: ...(small) resolution and detection: use a resolution as small as possible while having the detection still working (so it would perform faster) and perhaps couple it with LK tracking: look for people with a haar cascade, if a person is found, get the centre of the bounding box(or ideally a strong feature location), stop the haar detection and track the location with LK until you loose tracking (and you need to look for people again). Another way might be actually training your own haar cascade for your setup if you have enough experience with opencv

Comment: If I'm not wrong, haar cascade does not work well unless the entire person is in the frame ? I'm not trying to track humans specifically, like for example, if a man is walking his dog, both the man and his dog should have an individual bounding box.